# Curved Ceiling with Depth

Tags: objects, bezier-curves, extrude

I am trying to figure out how to get to this shape of ceiling but failed to figure out what is the technique or how to approach it.

Attached is an image on how I want it to appear (Done through Sketchup) using Arc, Offset (*Inset* in Blender), push/pull (*Extrude* in Blender)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scale a cube on Z, bevel one of its edges:

[image]

Inset (<kbd>i</kbd>) the face:

[image]

Extrude (<kbd>E</kbd>):

[image]

Cut an edge loop with the knife (<kbd>K</kbd> to activate, <kbd>Z</kbd> to cut through, <kbd>C</kbd> to cut perpendicularly):

[image]

Extrude the small protrusion:

[image]

Comment: You are my hero, short and to the point you have yourself a wonderful weekend